# jquery sortable: sorted item triggers reordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of items that represent `div` layers. When I sort one of these list items, I want their respective div layers to be sorted aswell.

**list: *these items are sortable***

```
<ul id="sortable">
   <li id="1">Div 1</li>
   <li id="2">Div 2</li>
   <li id="3">Div 3</li>
</ul>
```

**div layers: *these divs will be reordered***

```
<div id="div_container">
  <div id="div1">Div 1 item</div>
  <div id="div2">Div 2 item</div>
  <div id="div3">Div 3 item</div>
</div>
```

example: when `li#1` moves to the second place, then `div#1` goes to the second position automatically

**init**

```
$('#sortable').sortable();
```

Comment: May I ask how you will be sorting them?

Comment: @0x90, the name is somewhat misleading - jQuery sortable means you can drag and drop items into a new order. So what I assume the OP means is, you grab `1` and drag it below `3` (resulting in Div2 Div3 Div1), and the app automatically reshuffles the stuff in the `div_container` (into Div 2 item, Div 3 item, Div 1 item)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code could be what you want if I got what you are asking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/NsawH/84/

```
var indexBefore = -1;

function getIndex(itm, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (itm[0] === list[i]) break;
    }
    return i >= list.length ? -1 : i;
}

$('#sortable').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        indexBefore = getIndex(ui.item, $('#sortable li'));
    },
   stop: function(event, ui) {
       var indexAfter = getIndex(ui.item,$("#sortable li")); 
       if (indexBefore==indexAfter) return;
       if (indexBefore<indexAfter) {
           $($("#div_container div")[indexBefore]).insertAfter(
               $($("#div_container div")[indexAfter]));
       }
       else {
           $($("#div_container div")[indexBefore]).insertBefore(
               $($("#div_container div")[indexAfter]));
       }
   }
});
```

This code is portable since it does not use element ID's, however you should parametrize the sortable selector to be able to use them on any two lists eg. if you are binding to the sortable after init.

The code is jQuery dom modification friendly since it uses selector indexes and not node dom indexes. You will see on JSFiddle that i made the div_container a sortable , and it syncs back to the list.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you very much - for the code & the guide!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `change` event of the sortable (if you want real-time updates) or `stop` (to just read off the end state), and manually reorder the divs accordingly.